# Enforce gradle not to upgrade transitive dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am facing an issue with the automatic updgrade of transitive dependencies by gradle(6.7.1).
Consider two parent dependencies ***A*** and ***B***, both use different versions of **PICASSO** as transitive dependendency

```
A -> com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2 

B -> com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828
```

When builiding the android project , PICASSO is getting upgraded to *2.71828* automatically for both.
Since **PICASSO API INITIALISATION** is different for those 2 versions (*2.5.2 and 2.71828*) ,
***A*** happens to throw **NoSuchMethodException** .
How can i enforce gradle to use *specific* PICASSO versions for A and B .

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Gradle `strictly` constraint when declaring the transitive dependency.

For example:

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.4'
implementation('commons-codec:commons-codec') {
   version {
     strictly '1.9'
   }
}
```

Here `commons-code` is an internal dependency of `httpclient`, by adding `strictly` constraint to `commons-code`, `httpclient` will be forced to use version 1.9 regardless of what is defined internally in its project.

You can find more details [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version)

---

But let's say that in your case, dependency B is incompatible with an older version of Picasso, then you can extract one of the dependencies to a separate module and make the transitive dependency strict there.

Then you can either try adding the new module and see if it works or create the jar of the second dependency and add it to your project such that Gradle won't run conflict resolution in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strictly`, for more you can refer below link
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version